# How to add to text file from DataGridView without deleting whatever's already in there?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a school project in which we have to develop an application for an imaginary business that they can create new orders with, search past orders etc.
I have textboxes that add to a DataGridView and then when clicking a button, saves to a file called "List of Orders". How to make it so that it updates rather than wipes the whole thing?

My code so far:

```
      Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSaveOrder.Click
   Dim TimeStamp As String
   TimeStamp = DateAndTime.Now.ToString(" dd MM yyyy")

   Try

           Dim SaveF = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\VB\List of Orders.txt")
           With SaveF
               .Write("Order from: " + TxtName.Text + " Placed on: " + TimeStamp + vbCrLf)
               .Write(WriteDG())
               .Write("End of order")
               .Write("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
           .Close()
           MsgBox("Order submitted and File Saved")
       End With
       Catch ex As Exception

       End Try
   End Sub
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Environment.NewLine`

```
File.AppendAllText("C:\VB\List of Orders.txt", Environment.NewLine + "Order from: " + TxtName.Text + " Placed on: " + TimeStamp)
```

Or use `StreamWriter`

```
Using stwriter As new StreamWriter("C:\VB\List of Orders.txt", true)
    stwriter.WriteLine("Order from: " + TxtName.Text + " Placed on: " + TimeStamp)
End Using
```